# What happened to gstreamer-ffmpeg and can I replace it?

Tags: debian, ffmpeg, gstreamer

While trying to solve an issue about loading MPEG videos in Matlab, I found several suggestions to install the FFmpeg plugin for Gstreamer.

However, I can't find this functionality on Debian 9 [[1]](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gstreamer1.0-ffmpeg). It was available on Debian 7, though [[2]](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg).

This is not really an XY question. I'm still looking for alternatives for my issue with Matlab, but I am also interested in knowing what changed in Gstreamer or if I'm assuming anything wrong. Is there another package that supplies the functionality I was expecting from `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`?

[1] - https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gstreamer1.0-ffmpeg
[2] - https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was renamed to [gstreamer-libav](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gstreamer1.0-libav)

Comment: Is it a transparent replacement for `gstreamer-ffmpeg`?

Comment: Looks like its a direct clone (you can see the commits from libav) : https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-ffmpeg